# User name and password error during ArcGIS Server connection from ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, error

I get this error message, when I try to connect to our ArcGIS Server. I can reach that from browser with the same address. I get this error, when I try to connect from ArcMap, without any loading or any sign of real connecting.

> We were unable to connect to .... Error: Make sure you type in your user name and password correctly.

What can be the problem?

I'm not sure about my password or user name are wrong. According to my memories, an administrator user, who was picked up into the server's manager site with admin role should be able to log in. I tried with disabled firewalls too.

Comment: My ArcMap can't even connect to ArcGIS Online automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If ArcGIS Server is using Windows domain User / Role stores, you will need to prefix your login with your domain name.

For example, if my windows domain is XNET.gov, my log in username would be "XNET\btelliot".